# How can I find out which Git branches affect a given subdirectory?

Tags: git

Given a base branch `master` and subdirectory `A` in that branch, how can I list out all branches whose differences from `master` contain changes in the contents of `A`?

**My use case**: I'm doing a [subtree split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/17864475#17864475) on an active repository with lots of branches and I need to migrate all the affected branches as well. I'd like to avoid having to manually inspect every branch's changes or contacting all the branch owners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up scripting this out as:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

BASE_BRANCH=$1
DIR=$2

while read -r branch; do
    while read -r file; do
        if [ ${file:0:${#DIR}} == "$DIR" ] ; then
            echo "$branch"
            break
        fi
    done < <(git --no-pager diff --name-only $BASE_BRANCH...$branch)
done < <(git branch -a --no-merged $BASE_BRANCH | cut -c 3-)
```

This takes two arguments, the base branch (`master` in my example) and the subdirectory to check (in my example, I'd provide `A/` with a slash to avoid prefix matches that aren't actually a directory).

The outer loop iterates through all the branches that have not been merged to the base branch. Then inner loop iterates through all the files in each that have been modified from the base branch. When a file's prefix matches, the branch name is sent to output.